# button on android widget to pass a shell command

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-widget, adb

Is there a way I can add a button on widget to just pass a shell command without having to use any broadcasting or broadcast receiver ?

Please help.

I have implemented the following code in my class that extends the AppWidgetProvider:

```
package com.example.dumpserwidget;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import com.example.dumpserwidget.ShellCommand;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    //package com.example.dumpser;




         public void Check(View v) throws Exception{
                Log.d("Click", "Button Clicked");
                ShellCommand.execute("dumpsys activity service com.example.dumpser > /data/tta/CurrentStatus.txt");

            }

    }
```

ignore ShellCommand. That is a class that I implemented to run shell commands. But what I need to know is if this structure will work ?
I am writing the output of ShellCommand on to a file. 
When I include the android:onClick= "Check" in the layout file, I am not able to load my widget. It gives me an error saying "Problem loading widget". But when I remove the android:onClick="Check" I am able to see my widget with the button. I am assuming that the Check method cannot be located. How do I resolve this ? Also I tried doing it programatically by writing this

```
Button button = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {try {
                QShellCommand.execute("dumpsys activity service com.example.dumpser > /data/tta/CapellaCurrentStatus.txt");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
```

Now, I get an error saying that "R cannot be resolved to a variable". Why am I facing this ? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: what shell command do you want to pass?

Comment: Please put code into your question via the "Edit" link below your post. Code in comments is impossible to read.

Comment: Your code is missing a catch. Have you written ShellCommand?

Comment: Tried using Button programatically. Facing another issue now. Please check my edited question @StephanBranczyk

Answer (score 0):

The trickiest part will be to write ShellCommand for non-rooted devices (I assume you want your app to run on non-rooted devices, not just rooted ones). Normally, I'd tell you that this wasn't possible.

But here is a guy that did just that [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en).

And his solution is open source: 
https://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/

Sorry for providing a link-only answer. I would still need to study his code to see how he did that.